# tinyMCE blur event

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, onblur, rte

Hello
I want to do some stuff when user finished writing in the tinyMCE textarea and click somewhere outside (onBlur).
So far I haver try:

```
$('#id_topic_text_parent').live('blur',function(){
    alert('asd')
//I saw #id_topic_text_parent in firebug, it is span containing the tiny mce
});
```

also

```
$('#id_topic_title').blur(*and*)live('blur...
tinyMCE.activeEditor.blur(*and*)live('blur...
```

But it wont work.
Can you assist me.

Answer (score 17):

according to [http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:event.tinymce.Editor.blur](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.blur)

This works for me

```
setup : function(ed) {
    ed.on('blur', function(e) {
        alert('blur');
    });
},
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use this approach to solve your issue. When initializing tinymce set the setup paramter to the following (inside `tinyMCE.init({...})`

```
...
theme: "advanced",   // example param
plugins = 'code',    // example param
setup : function(ed) {
    ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {

        var dom = ed.dom;
        var doc = ed.getDoc();

        tinymce.dom.Event.add(doc, 'blur', function(e) {
            // Do something when the editor window is blured.
            alert('blur!!!');
        });
    });
},
cleanup: true,      // example param
...
```

Comment: Is it correct to paste your code into tiny_mce_init.js ? Because I do that and it is not working, there are no errors too.

Comment: no it is not, but i wasn't talking about modifying it! i edited my post to show you that setup is a parameter you set when initializing tinymce

Comment: Ok, that is what I did with tinymce_init.js, but it is not triggering the alert popup when blurring tinyMCE editor... is there something else that I must do ?

Comment: no, don't do it editing tinymce_init.js, have a look here (http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/%22For_Dummies%22) on howto initialize tinymce (especially the part with tinymce.init)

Comment: Thariama tinymce_init.js is the very same file from howto you gave me. You can see part of my code here, please take a look ---->  http://jsfiddle.net/FUCKy/3/

Comment: sorry, my fault (i somehow thoguht you were editing the source files) , you are right. this is a legal way to do it. can you tell me what browser you use to test it? (i am using FF 3.6 and it works)

Comment: I'm developing on Chrome at the moment... so far I have not test it on other browesers, but I'm looking for complex solusion.

Comment: my solution works for FF only - sry (if i find another more applicable solution i will let you know)

Comment: `getDoc()` does not work in Chrome (document won't issue the blur event there), `getWin()` works fine for me.

Comment: Is nobody seriously going to mention the comedic value in the auto generated token by JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Please use

```
function myCustomOnChangeHandler(inst) {
        alert("Some one modified something");
        alert("The HTML is now:" + inst.getBody().innerHTML);
}

tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        onchange_callback : "myCustomOnChangeHandler"
});
```

Ref: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:onchange_callback

This function is called once the user "blurs" the area;

Comment: Yes, but it's called even on copy/paste and any other command like bold etc. Not an option. :)

Comment: I use that function to determine when the editor is initialized, and then call `tinymce.dom.Event.add(tinyMCE.getInstanceById('editor-id').getWin(), 'blur', function(){ //do whatever});`

Answer (score 1):

I used this to close the external toolbar on blur, it *seems* to work (tested only on FF at the moment)

```
function showHideBar(sho,aid) { // aid=id not used
    if(sho) {
        $( ".mceToolbar,.mceExternalClose" ).show();
    } else {
        $( ".mceToolbar,.mceExternalClose" ).hide();
    }
}

tinyMCE.init({

    // ....

    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "external",
    resize : true,
    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.onInit.add(function(ed, event) {
            $(ed.getBody()).blur(function() {
                // alert("blur");
                showHideBar(false,ed.id);
            });

            $(ed.getBody()).focus(function() {
                // alert("focus");
                showHideBar(true,ed.id);
            });

        });
    },

    // ....

}
```

Comment: I tried something along these lines, (just the blur part) and it seemed to work everywhere except Safari on iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
$('#id_topic_text_parent textarea').live('blur', function() {
   alert('asd');
});
```

Can you post the html for the #id_topic_text_parent span?

<strike>$('#id_topic_text_parent').find('textarea').blur(function(){
   alert('asd');
});</strike>

Comment: #id_topic_text_parent is created by tinyMCE after the page is loaded so nope this is not working.

Comment: isn't there a function when you call tinyMCE that fires once tinyMCE has loaded? you could put this in there.

Comment: added live() function which will account for newly created elements

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have textarea:

```
<textarea id="mytext">
```

And you initialized TinyMCE editor:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#mytext',
    // ...
});
```

You can bind "onblur" event using such code:

```
tinyMCE.get('mytext').on('blur', function(e) {
    console.log(this); // "this" contains tinymce.Editor object
});
```

Reference and details: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.focusevent/

Answer (score 0):

If unable to do this on init, you can do this any time afterwards by simply selecting the editor by the textarea id then add the blur event.

If your textarea id is for example 'editor_2', ie

```
<textarea id="editor_2"></textarea>
```

and your javascript init code is similar to as follows,

```
tinyMCE.init({selector: '#editor_2'});
```

Then you can put this anywhere afterwards in JS:

```
tinyMCE.get('editor_2').on('blur', e => console.log("editor_2 blur event", e));
```

Tested OK on v4.